# Date not saving the correct value in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am getting the year and month of the current day and year today and is displaying the correct values on my textbox. However when I start submitting it into the database, the value becomes 2014 at default and not the value of the textbox. What seems to be the problem?

```js
function YearMonth() {
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getFullYear();
  var t = d.getUTCMonth()+1;
  var x = n + "-" + t ;
  
  document.getElementById("num").value = x;
}
```

```html
 <td><input type="text" id="num" name="num"></td></tr>
 
<input type= "button" name= "button_go" onclick="YearMonth()" id= "button_go" value= "GO" /> 
<input type= "submit" name= "submit" id= "submit_form" value= "Submit" />
```

```php
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "_db";
        $connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

            if ($connection->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
            }       

$count = $_POST['num'];

       $sql = "INSERT INTO table (no)
            VALUES ($count)";

            if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) 
            {

            } 
            else
            {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connection->error;
            }
```

Comment: What is the result of "SHOW CREATE TABLE no;" on mysql?

Comment: The num value is that you're getting is `2019-5` How about the data type of `no` in your table ?

Comment: the value 2014 only

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I tried int, year and varchar but it is still only getting the value 2014

Comment: Are you sure, your javascript submit function posts the value to your php server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in your `INSERT` query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (no) VALUES ($count)";
```

because you are not quoting `$count`, this translates to

```
INSERT INTO table (no) VALUES (2019-5)
```

which MySQL then converts to

```
INSERT INTO table (no) VALUES (2014)
```

Adding quotes around `$count` will solve your problem for now:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (no) VALUES ('$count')";
```

but you should really switch to prepared statements to avoid SQL injection risks. Something like:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO table (no) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $count);
$stmt->execute();
```

Had you used prepared statements originally you wouldn't have had this issue to begin with.

Comment: Didn't saw that I was missing a quote! Thank you so much for the clear explanation!